# Дромедар или дромадер — как же все-таки правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Одногорбого верблюда называют то так, то этак. По крайней мере, я встречаю оба варианта. А как же все-таки правильно и откуда взялось такое разночтение?
Как по мне, то произносить "дромадер" как-то удобнее)))

Comment: А ещё слышал вариант "дродемар"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты в общем-то в равной мере нормативны. Но словари обычно первым дают "дромадер".

Причина разного написания (и произношения) в том, что английский и французский язык по-разному заимствовали это слово из арабского, в котором гласные (даже "внутренние") не принадлежат корню, это словообразовательный и словоизменительный элемент. Дромадер - французский вариант, дромедар - английский.

Comment: Пусть англичане сами язык ломают, а мы будет говорить как удобнее "дромадер")))))